# how to check the textbox value user enter the value in textbox is right or wrong using ajax Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I m working with ajax jquery Search Functionality.

when I search the record in textbox then get the record but when I search false record then get the false record? that is the issue

table:

[image]

Emploee.aspx

```
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        Search Record:   <asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                         <input id="btnsearch" type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchrecord()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>           
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <table id="tbl" border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>StudentName</th>
                            <th>StudentAddress</th><br /><br />
                            <th>Edit</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>



       function searchrecord(studname) {

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "WebForm1.aspx/search",
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: "{ studname:'" + $("#txtsearch").val() + "' }",
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger

                        if (data.d == $("#txtsearch").val()) {

                            debugger

                            txt = "<tr><td>" + data.d + "</td></tr>";
                            $("#tbl").append(txt);
                            alert('you enter right record');

                        }

                        else if (data.d != $("#txtsearch").val()) {

                            alert('you enter wrong record');

                        }

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('search Error');  //now whatever i search then this run
                    },
                });
            }
```

Emploee.aspx

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string search(string studname,bool flg)
        {
            string data = "";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT studname FROM tblstud WHERE studname LIKE @studname and active=@flagTrueOrFalse", con);
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studname", "%" + studname + "%");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = flg;

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    studname = reader[0].ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
            }

            reader.Close();
            data = studname;
            return data;
        }
```

how to solve if-else condition ajax logic?

main get data list:

```
function GetData() {
                $.ajax({

                    url: 'Emploee.aspx/GetData',
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        data = JSON.parse(data.d);
                        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                            $("#tbl").append('<td>' + element.studname + '</td>');
                            $("#tbl").append('<td>' + element.studaddress + '</td>');
                            $("#tbl").append('<td><input type="button" id="btnupdate" value="Update" onclick="Update(' + element.studid + ', \'' + element.studname + '\' ,\'' + element.studaddress + '\')" /></td>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('Not Get Data')
                    },
                });
            }
```

simple, I want the add an if-else condition when the user enters the true record then add the record and the user gets a false record then gets the alert message box?

I want to set below condition in the above ajax:

```
if(textbox value match then going inside)
{
  txt = "<tr><td>" + data.d + "</td></tr>";
  $("#tbl").append(txt);
}
else if(textbox value not match then going inside)
{alert("please proper record enter");}
```

**Console log:**

[image]

**preview:**

```
{Message: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'flg'.",…}
Message: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'flg'."
StackTrace: "   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)"
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
```

**Response**

```
{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027flg\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

Comment: Comment out line $(‘#btnSearch’).onclick and its closing part }); you already calling function from button. This appends multiple anonymous functions to the search button.

Comment: @bestinamir thanks but when I add this line ```if (data.indexOf( $("#txtsearch").val()) > 1) ``` give an error Uncaught TypeError: data.indexOf is not a function

Comment: @bestinamir how to solve this problem where I need to add proper logic? I m facing this problem last week.

Comment: Set breakpoint to see what gets returned by Ajax as shown here, error means data is not string type. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CoESC2XGZLg

Comment: problem is that whatever i search then get the result If i comment this line ``` if (data.indexOf( $("#txtsearch").val()) > 1) ```  then show my console log:```headers :   { studname:'suraj' } and preview {d: "suraj"} d: "suraj" and response {"d":"suraj"}``` simple , I want add a if else condition when user enter true record then add the record and user get false record then get the alert message box

Comment: @bestinamir I know the problem but My logic is not proper

Answer (score 0):

The condition (data == "#txtsearch") will most likely never meet. 
I am guessing that you wanted to write

```
if (data.indexOf( $("#txtsearch").val()) > 1)
```

To compare the data. 
Anyway, is not very efficent, and my want to use the success and error callback properly to achieve wat you want.

Comment: ```if (data.indexOf($("#txtsearch").val()) > 1) { ```  that line give an error : Uncaught TypeError: data.indexOf is not a function

Comment: how to solve this problem and how to achieve this search functionality? help

Answer (score 0):

rahul I think there is no issue with your ajax request. you can check this by console.log(data)  in your success function. 
but as your code explains that you are appending the result directly to your 
$("#tbl") element that means you are appending not deleting previous results. so I suggest you create another element at the end of the table link I am sure this will help.

```
         //end of table tag then add this element 
         <span id="result"></span>
         //changes in success
         success: function (data) {

                        txt = "" + data.d + "";
                              $("#result").text(txt);
                        //$("#tbl").append(txt);

                    },
```

Comment: thanks for the support but not work ```</thead></table>
 <span id="result"></span>``` and ```txt = "" + data.d + ""; $("#result").text(txt);```

Comment: I want to set the if-else condition on search textbox when user enter a right value than get the record and when user enter a false  value than get the alert("you enter the wrong record")

Comment: Please share the Screenshot of console.log(data) your server response data that you get in success. then I will able to help you

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWv69.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0J2R.png

Comment: as your SS explains that you have a josn format return and in this a veriable d
you need to compare the    

                 if(data.d ==$("#txtsearch").val()){
                                            }

Comment: ```if(data.d ==$("#txtsearch").val()){ }```  not working this condition if I enter wrong value then add the record.

Comment: You are confused first of all clear your code keep calm and start debugging. because your HTML and javascript code is not clear  Please try to make your code clean then you can easily debug. or share a code snippet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207822/discussion-between-rahul-and-harsimranjit-singh).

Comment: you need to pass flag variable as a data in ajax request

Comment: I change my logic if else condition and web method and issue is solved I remove the flag variable SQL server management studio

Comment: also, change the if-else condition ajax call logic

Comment: Okay, sounds great.!!

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that I would like to whenever you try to search the student, please **remove Html before appending** the response data. so it would avoid confusion if you update content multiple times.

Also, one thing that I notice is that you have taken 2 parameters in the SQL query but you are not passing @flagTrueOrFalse  parameter. so make it proper. if still facing the problem then please give us more details so we cal helps you.

Comment: still I m facing this issue can u tell me what detail you need?

Comment: when I uncomment this line ```SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT studname FROM tblstud WHERE studname LIKE @studname and active=@flagTrueOrFalse", con);```  give error:'Must declare the scalar variable "@flagTrueOrFalse".'  database field value ```flag   bit```

Comment: Pass another parameter same as  @Studname

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studname", "%" + studname + "%");

also, clear your existing data before appending the new response


Also can you  please share the detail what actually you getting in the response Object data after searching the invalid content?

Comment: Hi @Rahul, I think you need to search only active records because I am not able to see any option on UI that has the advance option for search active/Inactive student.  so you don't have to take a parameter so pass the static value true in the SQL command parameter, if you don't want to pass static then you may take bool datatype with default value eg. bool flag=true. so it'll take default value if you not passing else override when you pass the flag value

Comment: now tell me which place should be I m going to wrong?

Comment: I take a flag field and how to set the flag in ajax? help?

Comment: Hi @Rahul you need to pass value in ajax something like mention below

 data: { "studname" : $("#txtsearch").val(),"flag":true  },

else you can change the in the server side like below 

c# :

 public static string search(string studname,bool flg=true)

Jquery :

 data: { "studname" : $("#txtsearch").val() },

Comment: You don't need to append on the table you need to override the HTML content of previously search.